# Execute dynamic query and print to file

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a script with dynamic query. I want to execute the query and output its result to a file. I can't seem to figure out how to output result of an "execute" statement.

Sample code below.

```
declare @sql_text varchar(300)

select @sql_text = select 1
exec (@sql_text) > output.txt
```

To give more context. My actual script would be looping through the dynamic query and output to different files (dynamic filename as well).

Answer (score 0):

You set the output file via the -o parameter to the isql client to execute the SQL. This will send the output to a file from any SQL be that normal or dynamic SQL.

So put the SQL in an input file and then run

isql -U user - P password -S  -i input_filename -o output.txt

You can't call directly to a operating system file from within ASE itself without enabling xp_cmdshell which is a potential security issue (as it allows O/S commands to be run as the user running the Sybase dataserver) and is therefore prohibited in most sites.